# Mongodb cluster Could not find host matching read preference { mode: "primary" } for set rs0

Tags: mongodb, cluster-computing

I am deploying a mongodb sharding, I have deployed a replica set in two machines:

```
rs.status()



 "members" : [
    {
        "_id" : 0,
        "name" : "mongo-shard-1:[port]",
        "health" : 1,
        "state" : 1,
        "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
        "uptime" : 693,
        "optime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1536595866, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(13)
        },
    },
    {
        "_id" : 1,
        "name" : "rs-mongo-shard-1:[port]",
        "health" : 1,
        "state" : 2,
        "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
        "uptime" : 665,
        "optime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1536595866, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(13)
        },
        "optimeDurable" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1536595866, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(13)
        },
    }
],
"ok" : 1,
"operationTime" : Timestamp(1536595866, 1),
"$clusterTime" : {
    "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1536595866, 1),
    "signature" : {
        "hash" : BinData(0,"QwasVYlskhD/0CkuF+4usWfwMHI="),
        "keyId" : NumberLong("6599506821294063618")
    }
}


mongo.conf 



security:  authorization: enabled keyFile: /[path]/mongo-keyfile replication: replSetName: "rs0"
```

and configsvr in three machine and also a mongos in machine.
I try to add my replica into mongos, but I got an error:

> "ok" : 0,
>    "errmsg" : "Could not find host matching read preference { mode: \"primary\" } for set rs0",
>    "code" : 133,
>    "codeName" : "FailedToSatisfyReadPreference",